# .htaccess не скрывает файлы, разрешенные в .htaccess уровнем выше

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Apache 2.4
Файловая система:

```
/    
.htaccess
test.php
    /folder
        .htaccess
        test.php
```

.htaccess в корне сайта:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?i)(test)\.php$">
    Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

.htaccess в директории folder:

```
Require all denied
```

Описанные правила должны выполнять задачу: разрешать test.php в корне сайта и запрещать /folder/test.php.
Однако, /folder/test.php также доступен.

Comment: Директивы файла .htaccess действуют для каталога, в котором размещён такой файл, и для всех его подкаталогов. То есть вы разрешили доступ к test.php во всех подкаталогах.

Comment: Отчасти верно. Но в подкаталоге (folder) я по идее запретил доступ правилом "Require all denied".

Comment: Это не так работает. Сначала все директивы собираются вместе, затем выполняются запрещающие директивы, потом разрешающие. То есть в подкаталоге folder запрещены все файлы, кроме test.php.